# I would like to create new columns for the original table in R

Tags: r, dplyr, mutated

This is my current coding for data wrangling.

```
crime_89 <- crime %>%
  filter(state_name %in% c("Georgia", "Pennsylvania", "West Virginia"), !is.na(rape_legacy)) %>%
  mutate(treat = case_when(year < 1989 ~ 0, 
                           TRUE ~ 1),
         id = case_when(state_name == "Georgia" ~ 1,
                        state_name == "Pennsylvania" ~ 2,
                        state_name == "West Virginia" ~ 3),
         crime_rate = 100 * (violent_crime + homicide + rape_legacy + robbery + aggravated_assault + property_crime + burglary + larceny + motor_vehicle_theft) / population )
```

I know that `mutate` from `dplyr` is the tool to create new columns.

The problem is that this `crime89` is the narrow scope from the original data limited to specific states. I would like to use the original data `crime` that has all lists of the states. Then, `id` columns should be different; counting from `Alaska` as 1 ...... to `Wyoming` as 51. **I don't know how to  create `id` columns with this condition without using `case_when`** **typing all states individually.**

Plus, I also need to create `treat` columns depending on the states.
The yardstick is the year the law was launched and '1' means treated status.
For example, `"Georgia", "Pennsylvania", "West Virginia"` are in 1989 so this is why I typed like this::

```
 mutate(treat = case_when(year < 1989 ~ 0, 
                           TRUE ~ 1),
```

However, not all of the states have the same year of the law. For example,
`"Idaho", "Mississippi", "Oregon"` is 1990 so the code should be

```
  mutate(treat = case_when(year < 1990 ~ 0, 
                            TRUE ~ 1))
```

**In the case covering all states, I don't know how to create new columns `treat` in `mutate` for different states at once.**

This is the original data `head(crime)` and the year is from 1979 to 2016.

```
 year state_abbr state_name population violent_crime homicide rape_legacy rape_revised robbery aggravated_assault
1 1979                        220099000       1208030    21460       76390           NA  480700             629480
2 1979         AK     Alaska     406000          1994       54         292           NA     445               1203
3 1979         AL    Alabama    3769000         15578      496        1037           NA    4127               9918
4 1979         AR   Arkansas    2180000          7984      198         595           NA    1626               5565
5 1979         AZ    Arizona    2450000         14528      219        1120           NA    4305               8884
6 1979         CA California   22696000        184087     2952       12239           NA   75767              93129
  property_crime burglary larceny motor_vehicle_theft caveats
1       11041500  3327700 6601000             1112800        
2          23193     5616   15076                2501        
3         144372    48517   83791               12064        
4          70949    21457   45267                4225        
5         177977    48916  116976               12085        
6        1511021   496310  847148              167563
```

Comment: It is advisable to ask one question at a time. Which question do you want to tackle first?

Comment: `id = as.integer(factor(state_name))`

Comment: I am sorry for asking two questions at the same time. I bolded two questions as you can see and I need both.

Comment: But I cannot tell what exactly the second question is asking probably you mean `case_when(state_name %in% c("Georgia", "Pennsylvania", "West Virginia") & year < 1989 ~0, state_name %in% c("Idaho", "Mississippi", "Oregon") & year < 1990~ 0, true~1)` THIS OF COURSE CAN BE REDUCED FURTHER

Comment: Originally, I separate data depending on the same year of the state. So I can apply ```case_when``` immediately because ```crime89``` indicates the states with the law in 1989 only. However, in the case of all states, not every state has the same year of 1989. So i cannot apply ```case_when``` with year 1989 only. I need to set all of the states with its year not 1989 only. I need to set the variable ```treat``` for each state depending on its year

Comment: Sorry I do not understand your statement. Consider the `id` part only

Comment: ```treat``` is the binary variable with 0 and 1. 1 means the law enacted periods. 0 is not. For example, for the variable of treat in Georgia, year from 1979 to 1988 should be 0 and year from 1989 to 2016 should be 1. However, for the variable of treat in Idaho, year from 1979 to 1989 should be 0 and year from 1990 to 2016 should be 1. As you can see, their enacted law year is different. I need to create ```treat``` columns with this yardstick depending on each state at once.

Comment: How do you know the enact year? ie how do you determine that Georgia is 1989 while Idaho is 1990?

Comment: For Alabama, the variable should be 1 for all years since enacted law already before 1979.

Comment: But how do you know when the law was enacted?? That is my question

Comment: The information on enacted year is based on the historical fact(data) but unfortunately, the original data ```crime``` did not include this information so I need to apply this information for each state in ```mutate``` if possible.

Comment: Consider creating a dataframe that has all the enacted years for all the states then you can join/merge the dataframe to this data on states and then just do a year comparison.

Comment: so your suggestion is creating ```NEWDATA``` and apply like this?  ```mutate(treat = case_when(year < NEWDATA ~ 0, TRUE ~ 1)```

Comment: No my suggestion is create a `df2 <- data.frame(state_name =c('Alabama', 'Georgia') , enacted_year = c(1979, 1989))`, then do `left_join(your_current_dataframe, df2) %>% mutate(treat = year >=enacted_year)`

Comment: ```"Georgia", "Pennsylvania", "West Virginia"```  share the same year. Do I have to put individually like ```c(1989, 1989, 1989)```?

Comment: Yes. All the states.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want to do?

I've reduced the sample data to only what's needed to address the two questions.

By mutating the state variables to `factor` you can get the order you want. Assuming alphabetical is okay, you can then create an ID column taking the integer of the factored `state_name`.

You could use the `state_abbr` in the `case_when` to reduce the typing, and I'm assuming `treat` is then determined by both `year` and matching the state?

```r
library(tidyverse)

crime <- tribble(
  ~year, ~state_abbr, ~state_name,
  1979, "AK", "Alaska", 
  1979, "AL", "Alabama", 
  1979, "AR", "Arkansas", 
  1979, "AZ", "Arizona", 
  1979, "CA", "California", 
  1989, "GA", "Georgia", 
  1989, "PA", "Pennsylvania", 
  1989, "WV", "West Virginia",
  1990, "ID", "Idaho", 
  1990, "MS", "Mississippi", 
  1990, "OR", "Oregon"
)

crime %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with("state_"), factor),
    id = as.integer(state_name),
    treat = case_when(
      year == 1989 & state_abbr %in% c("GA", "PA", "WV") ~ 1,
      year == 1990 & state_abbr %in% c("ID", "MS", "OR") ~ 1,
      TRUE ~ 0
    )
  )
#> # A tibble: 11 × 5
#>     year state_abbr state_name       id treat
#>    <dbl> <fct>      <fct>         <int> <dbl>
#>  1  1979 AK         Alaska            2     0
#>  2  1979 AL         Alabama           1     0
#>  3  1979 AR         Arkansas          4     0
#>  4  1979 AZ         Arizona           3     0
#>  5  1979 CA         California        5     0
#>  6  1989 GA         Georgia           6     1
#>  7  1989 PA         Pennsylvania     10     1
#>  8  1989 WV         West Virginia    11     1
#>  9  1990 ID         Idaho             7     1
#> 10  1990 MS         Mississippi       8     1
#> 11  1990 OR         Oregon            9     1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>